# Pandas: Filter dataframe with multiindex by most recent date per base level

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a pd.DataFrame with the following format:

```
                    dimension    datekey  ...    tbvps workingcapital
ticker calendardate                       ...                        
A      2020-03-31         MRT 2020-04-30  ...   16.026   1.226000e+09
AAL    2020-03-31         MRT 2020-03-31  ...  123.058  -1.203800e+10
       2020-06-30         MRT 2020-06-30  ...  138.105  -4.211000e+09
AAP    2020-03-31         MRT 2020-04-18  ...  150.120   1.740946e+09
       2020-06-30         MRT 2020-07-11  ...  148.265   1.957966e+09
```

I'd like to select only the rows with the most recent calendardate per ticker, so the output would look like this:

```
                    dimension    datekey  ...    tbvps workingcapital
ticker calendardate                       ...                        
A      2020-03-31         MRT 2020-04-30  ...   16.026   1.226000e+09
AAL    2020-06-30         MRT 2020-06-30  ...  138.105  -4.211000e+09
AAP    2020-06-30         MRT 2020-07-11  ...  148.265   1.957966e+09
```

I know how to do this by looping over the level(0) index values and using df.loc[ticker].last('1D'), but I'm looking for something faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `groupby` with `tail`

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).tail(1)
```